# Django pass PK from post to next page

Tags: django

I currently have a blog post feature on my site. I want users to be able to create sub posts
(build log ) off of the main posts.

I created this model with a FK to the Post model

```
class BuildLog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I then added a button on the post page and created a form. Everything is working as expected but when I submit the form I get the error

```
null value in column "post_id" of relation "blog_buildlog" violates not-null constraint
```

If I understand the error correctly it is saying I am not passing the PK of the post into the form.

Views

```
    def DetailPostView(request, pk):
        model = Post
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        form = CommentForm
        
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)#.order_by('-create')
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # A comment was posted
            comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                
                new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)            
                new_comment.author = request.user
                new_comment.post = post
                new_comment.save()
    
    
        context = {
            'post':post, 'form':form, 'comments':comments
            }
        return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
    
    
class BuildLogView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = BuildLog
    form_class = BuildLogForm
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BuildLog,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Url

```
path('build-log-form/', BuildLogView.as_view(), name='build-log-form'),
path('post/<int:pk>/', views.DetailPostView, name='post-detail')
```

How do I go about passing the post PK into the next view?

forms.py

```
class BuildLogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BuildLog
        fields = ['title' , 'content']
```

html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
```

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

```
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="PostForm" novalidate>
        <!--id="modelForm"-->
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="django-ckeditor-widget">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Build Log</legend>

            {{ form.title | as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.media }}
            {{ form.content | as_crispy_field | safe}}

        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Just incase their is any confusing It goes Post --> BuildLog(subpost)

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: Are you creating the BuildLogForm manually or by using a ModelForm? Please post your forms.py, your problem may be on it.

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka added forms.py However I don't think the issue lies in the form But rather I need something in the view to grab the post pk

Comment: @MeL added html to build log form